# Key repeats and ranges in Vim mappings

Tags: vim, dictionary, mapping, macvim

I want to define a mapping in my .gvimrc such that if the last key pressed is held, the triggered action is repeated. Specifically, I want to do something like

```
map <SPACE>t :set transparency-=1
map <SPACE>T :set transparency+=1
```

for MacVim, but I want the transparency to continue to be decreased/increased when t/T are held (don't want to have to keep pressing the spacebar).

If you have a suggestion for a nicer way to adjust the transparency, I would appreciate that also.

Separately, it would be nice to be able be able to type <kbd>20</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> and have the transparency decreased by 20; however, when I try I get an

```
E481: No range allowed.
```

How do I enable range specification?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For the keyboard clipart in markdown see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26207/how-to-format-as-keyboard-keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure about the first part of your question, but to get <kbd>20</kbd> <kbd>`<Space>`</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> to be able to do its job:

```
:map <space>t :<C-U>exe "set transparency-=".v:count1<CR>
```

- With `<C-U>` you remove the line range that is added to your ex command when you type <kbd>20</kbd> in Normal mode.
- With `exe` you execute 'dynamic' vimscript.
- `v:count1` is the count given for the last Normal mode command (20 in this example). And if there is no count given it defaults to 1.

For additional information see

```
:h v:count
:h v:count1
```

**Update:**

You can omit `exe` using `let` form instead of `set` one:

```
:map <space>t :<C-U>let &transparency-=v:count1<CR>
```

See `:h :let-&`.

Comment: hey thanks.. that was perfect. (well almost; the "set transparency -= " shouldn't have a space after the -=)